# Typescript access hashmap with string variable

Tags: typescript, hashmap

I made this simple code:

```
const testHashMap = {
    hello: "Hi",
    test: "Hey",
    blabla: "Halo"
}

const inputFromField : string = "hello";

alert(testHashMap[inputFromField]);
```

But the last line doesn't work because it demands that inputFromField will be from type `"hello" | "test" | "blabla"` and not a general string, how can I insist to use string? as it should be an input from the user in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly declare the type for your constant:

```js
const testHashMap: Record<string, string> = {
    hello: "Hi",
    test: "Hey",
    blabla: "Halo"
}
```

`Record<string,string>` is a more readeable form (syntactic sugar?) for `{[key: string]: string}`. You could have written the code above like this and it would mean the same:

```js
const testHashMap: {[key: string]: string} = {
    hello: "Hi",
    test: "Hey",
    blabla: "Halo"
}
```

Comment: Just from curiosity, could you show how it would be done without the `Record` interface?